# How many distinct sum of products are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Given a $k{\times}k$ matrix P, how many distinct sum of product values are possible for $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k} i{\times}j{\times} P(i,j)$.

Conditions: elements in P are integers that lie in the range $[0,n]$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k} P(i,j) = n$.

Comment: Presumably the $P(i,j)$ are integers

Comment: Yes, indeed they are. Just edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A possible approach:*

The minimum is $n$ achieved when $P(1,1)=n$, and the maximum is $k^2n$ achieved when $P(k,k)=n$. The range of integers including these extremes has $(k^2-1)n+1$ integers.

If $n$ is big enough compared with $k$, I think that you cannot achieve any number

- strictly between $k^2n-k$ (when $P(k,k)=n-1$ and $P(k,k-1)=1$) and $k^2n$, or
- strictly between $k^2n-2k+1$ (when  $P(k,k)=n-1$ and  $P(k-1,k-1)=1$) and  $k^2n-k$, or
- strictly between $k^2n-3k+2$  (when  $P(k,k)=n-1$ and  $P(k-1,k-2)=1$) and  $k^2n-2k$ (when $P(k,k)=n-2$ and $P(k,k-1)=2$),

and you continue this pattern.  For example $k^2n-3k+1$ is achievable when $P(k,k)=n-2$,   $P(k,k-1)=1$ and $P(k-1,k-1)=1$.

If you continue this pattern, at first glance you seem to be excluding $(k-1)+(k-2)+(k-3)+\cdots = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ terms, leaving $k^2n-n-\frac{k^2}{2}+ \frac{k}{2}+1$ terms.

I have not checked this, but it seems to give the correct answers when $n=1$ and $k=1$, when $n=2$ and $k=1$, and when $n=2$ and $k=2$, but not when $n=1$ and $k=2$.

Comment: my $n$ value is 784 and $k$ is 8.

Comment: @saikat: Then I think my expression might then predict $49365$ possible distinct sums.  Everything from $8$ through to $50176$ except for $28$ values above $43904$. No guarantees.

Comment: I will check for the results and try to see how it does for bigger values of $n$ and $k$. Thanks a lot for that great answer though. Also, even if we can't have a general closed form solution in terms of $n$ and $k$, how about a bound? I am looking for a tight upper bound on the solution.